# Enum flags doesn't append value

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I'm having a few issues in using a Flag enumeration.

My enumeration is the following (I declared the Flags attribute):

```
[Flags]
public enum Categ
{
    None = 0,
    Doors = 1,
    Views = 2,
    Rooms = 3,
    Spaces = 4
}
```

But when I try to use it in my code it seems that instead of appending the last value it replaces the first one:

```
var category = Categ.Doors | Categ.Rooms;
//category is always equal to Rooms only
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Flags so maybe I'm skipping some step.
Thank you very much!

Comment: `1 | 3 == 3` so your "Doors" are lost. The `|` is a bitwise-OR, not some concatenation

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, standard enums can only hold a value at a time. Enums decorated with the [Flags] attribute (and using powers of 2!) allows them to be treated as bit masks, storing multiple values. So, Categ.Doors | Categ.Rooms does not lose "Doors" as you suggest.

Comment: @swatsonpicken with the values that the OP used, "doors" is lost because the bitmask 1 (Doors) is *included* in the bitmask 3 (Rooms). Of course with powers of 2, this wouldn't happen

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, yes, you are quite right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding the `[Flags]` attribute doesn't really do anything to the enum other than affect how `.ToString()` works. You still need to use values that are powers of 2 for each elements:

```
[Flags]
public enum Categ
{
    None = 0,
    Doors = 1,
    Views = 2,
    Rooms = 4,
    Spaces = 8
    // then 16, 32, 64 etc.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As @DavidG has pointed out, the values need to be powers of two. Other options to ensure this are...

To use bit shifting:

```
[Flags]
public enum Categ
{
    None = 0,
    Doors = 1 << 0,
    Views = 1 << 1,
    Rooms = 1 << 2,
    Spaces = 1 << 3
}
```

Or, from C# 7.0 on, to use binary literals:

```
[Flags] 
public enum Categ
{ 
    None = 0b0000,
    Doors = 0b0001, 
    Views = 0b0010, 
    Rooms = 0b0100, 
    Spaces = 0b1000
}
```